# matplotlib:plot a line closed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plot a figure as below:

```
plt.plot(lon,lat,'ro-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

but the lines aren't closed.
How can I make them closed as polygons?
thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `matplotlib.pyplot.fill(lon,lat,fill=False)` instead of `plot()`.

See http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill for details. The color string refers to the interior, so to use red for the polygon, use

```
plt.fill(lon, lat, edgecolor='r', fill=False)
```

and continue to use `plot()` to place circles on the vertices if desired.

Answer (score 1):

A helper method I use:

```py
def plotPolygonOutline(points: List[Tuple[float, float]], color='r', lineWidth=1):
    x, y = map(list, zip(*points))
    x.append(x[0])
    y.append(y[0])
    plt.plot(x, y, marker='o', color=color, linewidth=lineWidth)
```