# Pythonic way to draw a bounded rectangle

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

You can do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

<generate-polygon-points>

plt.plot(polygon[:,0], polygon[:,1], 'r--', lw=2)
```

where `polygon` will contain vertices of a polygon in a n-by-2 numpy array, and these points are ordered in a counter-clockwise order (which allow plotting of the polygon of course). However this way the last edge is always missed out. Of course I can do another line of:

```
plt.plot(polygon[-1,:], polygon[0,:], 'r--', lw=2)
```

but is there anyway to group both into only one line of code - more pythonic way?

Comment: Could you simply concatenate the first pair of coordinates to the end of the array in your logic to generate the points then use one plot command to draw it?

Comment: I could but design wise it would really hurt from there... As it would be confusing later in the program (and for my collaborator) to decide the number of points of the polygon. It is doable, but I prefer things to be apparent.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469996/matplotlibplot-a-line-closed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understood your question, but if i do, I know an easier way for your probram which is using the turtle module

in fact, I have the code here!

```
import turtle

turtle = turtle.turtle()

for i in range(4):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
```

from me, this is my answear